# Turning first vertex of a line into a point

Tags: arcpy, point, coordinates, line, python-addin

```
import arcpy
import math
import pythonaddins

class Line(object):
"""Implementation for Projects_addin.Project1_2 (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.cursor = 3
    self.shape = "Line" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
def onLine(self, line_geometry):
    cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("NewL", ["SHAPE@"])
    cur.insertRow([line_geometry])
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    fields = arcpy.ListFields('NewL')
    length = False
    heightM = False
    heightF = False
    for field in fields:
        if field.name == 'Length':
            length = True
        elif field.name == 'HeightM':
            heightM = True
        elif field.name == 'HeightF':
            heightF = True
    if length == False:
        arcpy.AddField_management('NewL', 'Length', 'DOUBLE')
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    if heightM == False:
        arcpy.AddField_management('NewL', 'HeightM', 'DOUBLE')
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    if heightF == False:
        arcpy.AddField_management('NewL', 'HeightF', 'DOUBLE')
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('NewL', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    fid = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('NewL').getOutput(0))-1
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('NewL', 'NEW_SELECTION', ''' FID = {} '''.format(fid))
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    arcpy.CalculateField_management('NewL', 'Length', '!shape.length@meters!', 'PYTHON_9.3')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Source_Package', 'INTERSECT', 'NewL')

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Source_Package', ['SunElevati']) as cursor:
        for feat in cursor:
            new_heightM = math.tan(math.radians(feat[0]))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Source_Package', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.CalculateField_management('NewL', 'HeightM', '!Length!*{}'.format(new_heightM), 'PYTHON_9.3')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.CalculateField_management('NewL', 'HeightF', '!HeightM!*3.28089895', 'PYTHON_9.3')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

This code generates a line with attribution depending on the polygon it is overlapping. Is it possible to take the first vertex of the line and create a point in another feature class, while simultaneously transferring the attribution?

I was thinking (line_geometry.firstPoint.X, line_geometry.firstPoint.Y) would create the coordinates, but I am still considering other possibilities.

Edit 1:

```
point = arcpy.Point(line_geometry.firstPoint.X, line_geometry.firstPoint.Y)
pt_cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(Point Feature Here, ['SHAPE@'])
pt_cur.insertRow([point])
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

I added this to the end and I have created the point I desired, now I am working on transferring the attributes.

Edit 2:

I have also successfully added the attribution aspect.

Comment: Have you considered the [Feature Vertices To Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool?  Requires Advanced license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  In this line:

```
pt_cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(Point Feature Here, ['SHAPE@'])
```

Change the list containing only 'SHAPE@' to a list of the fields you want to update (including 'SHAPE@').

You'll want to grab the values in a SearchCursor.  Probably something like in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90376/7424) to [Using arcpy.da.InsertCursor to insert entire row that is fetched from search cursor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90372).

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar to that to add the attribution.

Comment: Your approach is actually significantly better than my idea, thanks again.